# How can I set data's in twig from Ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony, twig

I can't set data's in twig from Ajax response. `${id}`
I render content on front-end with jQuery template (use Ajax response), 
and I can't set data's in this template, twig give error:

> Unexpected character "$".

Hear my JavaScript:

```
function ajaxSearchForm() {
var template =
        "<tr>" +
        "<td>${id}</td>" +
        "<td>${dpId}</td>" +
        "<td>${name}</td>" +
        "<td>${price}</td>" +
        "<td>${discount}</td>" +
        "<td>${description}</td>" +
        "<td>${image}</td>" +
        "<td>${companyName}</td>" +
        "<td>${categoryName}</td>" +
        "<td><a class='btn btn-sm btn-default edit_link'></a><i class='fa fa-cart-plus' aria-hidden='true'></i>" +
        "{{ render(controller('MainBundle:Certificate:addCertificate', {'certificate': " + ${id} ", 'cart': 1215'} )) }} " +
        "</td>" +
        "</tr>";

var empty =
        "<tr>" +
        "<th colspan='10'>No result...</th>" +
        "</tr>";

$('#form_search_certificate button').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{ path('app.admin.search.certificate')}}",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('#form_search_certificate').serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            $("#search_result").empty();
            var dataParse = JSON.parse(data.result_search);
            if (dataParse.length !== 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < dataParse.length; i++) {
                    $.tmpl(template, {
                        "id": dataParse[i].id,
                        "dpId": dataParse[i].dp_id,
                        "name": dataParse[i].name,
                        "price": dataParse[i].price,
                        "discount": dataParse[i].discount.value,
                        "description": dataParse[i].description,
                        "image": dataParse[i].image,
                        "companyName": dataParse[i].company.name,
                        "categoryName": dataParse[i].category.name,
                        "cart_id": data.cart_id
                    }).appendTo("#search_result");
                }
            } else {
                $.tmpl(empty, {}).appendTo("#search_result");
            }
        }
    });
});
}
 ajaxSearchForm();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the whey How set data in my ajax url:
 
In Action, wich rendering this template must have field `cat_id` (i get hem from `return render()`).
 
Then in ajax template i get this `cat_id` and set in url:

```
url: '{{ path("app.admin.search.certificate", {"cartId": cart_id}) }}',
```

And all is work !

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing javascript variables into twig at this line,

```
"{{ render(controller('MainBundle:Certificate:addCertificate', {'certificate': " + ${id} ", 'cart': 1215'} )) }} " +
```

You need to call that render in the controller called by ajax and return the reponse of that render instead of trying to render that through javascript

Comment: I do this, but it doesn't work:

`$qwe = [$certificate, $cart];
$certificate = ' + ${id} ';
$cart = 1215;`